# Changing Regex to work with dot's c#

Tags: c#, regex, printing, 3d, g-code

Im using regex to seperate my G Code into seperate X,Y,Z,E,F commands.
using the regex below it works with commas.

`[GMXYZEF][-+]?[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?`

G1 X-5,300 Y5,110 E1,17440

But if i switch the commas to dot's it dosent work.

G1 X-5.300 Y5.110 E1.17440

What do i need to change in my regex to make it work?

Comment: Seriously? You didn't try just changing the `,` in your regex to  `\.`???

Comment: yes i did but now i know that was correct. But i thougt this didn't work since i'm using convert.todouble the dot dosent work. Now i know that i need to change the dot to a comma. So how can i do that?

Comment: Solved the problem with this line off code.
`string result = Regex.Replace(readContents, "[.]", ",", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 2):

Periods have [special significance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#AnyCharacter) in regular expressions, so you will need to escape it in your pattern:

```
[GMXYZEF][-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
```

Of course, to use this as a string in C#, you'll either have to escape the backslash, or use a verbatim string:

```
var regex = new Regex("[GMXYZEF][-+]?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?"); // escaped backslash 
var regex = new Regex(@"[GMXYZEF][-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?"); // verbatim string
```